# Why won't my TextView update/reset in android?

Tags: java, android, text, textview, settext

I have created a TextView, `public TextView textView;`, which I later define in my MainActivity.java in `onCreate`:

```
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
```

However, when I do set the text, it is not updating properly. Whenever I use the `setText` method, it does not update on the screen. The initial call to `setText` is in in a method called `recordClap()`.

```
    /**set text view*/
    textView.setText("listening...");
```

This text is not updated to the screen.

Lastly, I set the text to display "Success!" once certain conditions have been met.

```
    textView.setText("Success!");
```

For some reason this is the only call to 'setText' that works.

So, why is the TextView not updating the new text properly? Is there something I have left out?

Full code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private static final String TAG = "Clapper";
private static final long DEFAULT_CLIP_TIME = 1000;
private long clipTime = DEFAULT_CLIP_TIME;

/**create text view*/
public TextView textView;
private boolean continueRecording;
public static final int AMPLITUDE_DIFF_LOW = 10000;
public static final int AMPLITUDE_DIFF_MED = 18000;
public static final int AMPLITUDE_DIFF_HIGH = 32767; 
private int amplitudeThreshold=AMPLITUDE_DIFF_HIGH;
private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
private static String tmpAudioFile = null;

public boolean recordClap()
{
/**set text view*/
textView.setText("listening...");

Log.i(TAG, "record clap");
boolean clapDetected = false;

try
{

    tmpAudioFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    tmpAudioFile += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFile(tmpAudioFile);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.prepare();

    Log.i(TAG, "i've been prepared!");
}
catch (IOException io)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "failed to prepare recorder ", io);
}

recorder.start();
int startAmplitude = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
Log.i(TAG, "starting amplitude: " + startAmplitude);

do
{
    Log.i(TAG, "waiting while recording...");
    waitSome();
    int finishAmplitude = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
    int ampDifference = finishAmplitude - startAmplitude;
    if (ampDifference >= amplitudeThreshold)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "heard a clap!");
        /**here is the output to screen*/
        /**reset text view*/
        textView.setText("Success!");

        clapDetected = true;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "finishing amplitude: " + finishAmplitude + " diff: "
            + ampDifference);
} while (continueRecording || !clapDetected);

Log.i(TAG, "stopped recording");
done();

return clapDetected;
}

private void waitSome()
{
try
{
    // wait a while
    Thread.sleep(clipTime);
} catch (InterruptedException e)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "interrupted");
}
}

public void done()
{
Log.d(TAG, "stop recording");
if (recorder != null)
{
    if (isRecording())
    {
        stopRecording();
    }
        //now stop the media player
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
    }
}

public boolean isRecording()
{
    return continueRecording;
}

public void stopRecording()
{
    continueRecording = false;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("hello", "world!");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /**define text view*/
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

    /**run*/
    recordClap();

/**Restart Button*/    
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
        recordClap();
    }
  });
}
}
```

Comment: initial text is empty - nothing assigned to it

Comment: before you click the button - is the text empty?

Comment: My guess is that it is happening so fast you are not seeing it. Have you tried stepping (debugging) slowly through your program to make sure its changing? I'm almost certain the setTexts are being called from looking at your code.

Comment: I have set Log.i() messages to make sure they were passing through the steps, but I have not tried stepping - I will do that now - thanks for the advice

Comment: I checked your code. As @Jack said, 'waiting...' is passing so fast because you are calling `recordClap` method right after that. And it changes to `listening...` on my device. I didn't check `success` part because you said it is working, and also I  don't have any sound file I deleted this part of your code. As he said try debugging step by step.

Comment: @Jack - It was passing so fast that I could't see it - thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments, the change is happening so fast you are not seeing it. Try slowing it down, or increasing your waitSome possibly? But watch out - if I remember correctly in your waitSome() method, you are Thread.sleeping on the UI thread - which will cause the UI not to update during this time. So it may be happening like this (I can't remember exactly how the UI thread queueing works):

1. recordClap is called
2. textView.setText("listening") is called and put on the queue (but UI
   not updated yet)
3. Thread.sleep(1000) pauses UI thread
4. TextView says "listening" for a split second then moves on

Comment: +1 - I think that the text isn't changing properly because of how the UI updates - instead of `.setText` I used `.append` and all of the text I wanted did appear, but after the whole process had finished. So essentially, because of the way the UI thread works, I was rewriting the `.setText` and then the most updated version (the one that read "success!") was printing to the screen

Answer (score 0):

Kindly take a reference of textview i.e 
   `textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName)`;
 in recordclap() function before you set the text.

Thanks